# how to set local time based on time zone in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am developing a website where user will select the timezone from a dropdown. And in my database the datetime are stored in UTC format. How i can display his profile all other things as per timezone selected by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the timezone offset for the user and apply that to the UTC time each time you want show the date/time.

Comment: The offset will depend on DST too.